# User authentication problem after refreshing the browser in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

If the user try to refresh the page using refresh button of browser once he logged into the application (developed using Silverlight 4), he needs to re-authenticate himself means he needs to re-login to the application. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

How to maintain sessions in silverlight:

[Maintaining session in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307936/maintaining-session-in-silverlight)

http://girishhande.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-maintain-sessions-in-silverlight.html